# connecting samsung GT-S6102 to ubuntu for development

Tags: android

I am new to android development i would like to develop android apps for that purpose i would like to connect my Samsung GT-S6102 to my system(ubuntu 12.04LTS) but it is not connected and i followed all the steps that is installing required drivers and platforms and set up eclipse id .i developed a simple app which is in documentation it runs in emulator but i would like to test it in my device so please help me how to connect it and lastly i created the /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
in that i specified the rule as shown below
 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
and i  gave the  permissions to it also . So please help me for connecting it

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What does command "adb devices" returns?

Comment: adb devices command returns  the list of android devices which are connected to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable USB debugging.

It is usually Settings -> Development -> USB debugging.

Sometimes it is in Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging.